# Create new column in pandas based on the row value and sum of row values amount to zero

Tags: python-3.x, loops

```
prev_Item = ' '
prev_amount = 0
for i,row in df.iterrows():
   curr_Item     = row[11]
   curr_amount   = row[15]
   if (prev_Item == curr_Item):
       if (prev_amount + curr_amount) == 0:  
           df.loc[i-1, 'Mark'] = 'Delete'
       else:
           prev_amount = curr_amount

   prev_Item = curr_Item`
```

Scenario 1 : Input Dataframe

| Item | Price |
| --- | --- |
| Ball | -30.52 |
| Ball | -30.52 |
| Ball | 30.52 |
| Ball | 30.52 |
| Wicket | -9.99 |

Expected output as mentioned below

| Item | Price | Mark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ball | -30.52 | Delete |
| Ball | -30.52 | Delete |
| Ball | 30.52 | Delete |
| Ball | 30.52 | Delete |
| Wicket | -9.99 | None |

Scenario 2 : Input Dataframe

| Item | Price |
| --- | --- |
| Ball | -15.12 |
| Ball | -15.12 |
| Ball | 30.24 |
| Ball | -13.85 |
| Wicket | -9.99 |

Expected output as mentioned below

| Item | Price | Mark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ball | -15.12 | Delete |
| Ball | -15.12 | Delete |
| Ball | 30.24 | Delete |
| Ball | -13.85 | None |
| Wicket | -9.99 | None |

Comment: Mark the records as delete in data frame column mark based on the same item and sum of amount to zero

Answer (score 0):

```
prev_Price = 0

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    ## Assign column variables as row values
    curr_Item = row[11]
    curr_Price   = row[15]
    count,amount = 0,0

    if (curr_Item == prev_Item):
        if curr_Price+prev_Price == 0:
            df.loc[i,'Mark'] = 'Delete'
            df.loc[i-1,'Mark'] = 'Delete'
        else:
            prev_Price = curr_Price
            if df.loc[i,'Mark'] != 'Delete':
                count += 1
                amount += df.loc[i,'Amt']
                if amount == 0:
                    while count ==0:
                        df.loc[i-count, 'Mark'] = 'Delete'
                        count -= 1
    else:
        count,amount  = 0,0
        prev_Item = curr_Item
```

Can someone improvise my code

Comment: Need any information to understand the problem?